# variance of double sum

Tags: probability, statistics

why the following inequality

$var(\sum_{1\leq i\neq j\leq n} Wij)=n(n-1)E(W^2_{12})+n(n-1)E(W_{12}W_{21})+n(n-1)(n-2)E(W_{12}W_{13})+n(n-1)(n-2)E(W_{12}W_{23})+n(n-1)(n-2)E(W_{12}W_{31})+n(n-1)(n-2)E(W_{12}W_{32})-n(n-1)(4n-6)(E(W_{12}))^2 \mbox{ where }
W_{ij}(x)=\beta(X_i,x)(\beta(X_i,x)-\beta(X_j,x))K(h^{-1}d(X_i,x))K(h^{-1}d(X_j,x))\mbox{ with }(X_i) \mbox{ random variable identically distribued}, K \mbox{ is kernel}, d\mbox{ is metric}, h \mbox{ is integer} \mbox{ and } \beta \mbox{ is measurable function. }$

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: $\sum_{i,j}$ is double sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, let the notation $\mathcal D\{i,j\}$ represent selecting two distinct integers between $1$ and $n$, inclusive.  We can extend this to three or four distinct integers as needed.

$$\small\begin{align}&\qquad\mathsf{Var}\left({\sum_{\mathcal D\{i,j\}}}W_{i,j}\right)\\[1ex]&= {\sum_{\mathcal D\{i,j\}}\sum_{\mathcal D\{k,\ell\}}}\mathsf{Cov}(W_{i,j},W_{k,\ell})\\[1ex]&={{{\sum_{\mathcal D\{i,j\}}}\bigl(\mathsf{Var}(W_{i,j})+\mathsf{Cov}(W_{i,j},W_{j,i})\bigr)}+{{\sum_{\mathcal D\{i,j,k\}}}\bigl(\mathsf{Cov}(W_{i,j},W_{i,k})+\mathsf{Cov}(W_{i,j},W_{j,k})+\mathsf{Cov}(W_{i,j},W_{k,j})+\mathsf{Cov}(W_{i,j},W_{k,i})\bigr)}+{{\sum_{\mathcal D\{i,j,k,\ell\}}}\mathsf{Cov}(W_{i,j},W_{k,\ell})}}\\[1ex]&={{2!\binom{n}{2}\bigl(\mathsf{Var}(W_{1,2})+\mathsf{Cov}(W_{1,2},W_{2,1})\bigr)}+{3!\binom{n}{3}\bigl(\mathsf{Cov}(W_{1,2},W_{1,3})+\mathsf{Cov}(W_{1,2},W_{2,3})+\mathsf{Cov}(W_{1,2},W_{3,2})+\mathsf{Cov}(W_{1,2},W_{3,1})\bigr)}+{4!\binom n4\mathsf{Cov}(W_{1,2},W_{3,4})}}\end{align}$$

Everything else is just expanding out the covariance.

Comment: Thank you very much Graham Kemp.